# Is there a better way to write a Regex to match the case,

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to build a Regex which will discard the string if matched.

Case study: Discard the string if it starts with a literal square brackets `[]`

I've tried reading multiple articles on the web for solving the problem, and made a Regex that actually works for me

I've the following paragraph:

```
[Hello] How are you
Doing
 Hope you have a nice day!
[goodbye] cya 
Take care
```

The regex I'm using is `/^(?!\[.?\])/`

The result is as expected, I wanna know is there a better way to match it ?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? What does not work for you? Note it is StackOverflow, not [codereview.se].

Comment: The regex you say you're using `/^(?!\[.+\])/` is not the same regex as in the picture `/^[^\[.?\]]/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thankyou for the introduction to code review.

Comment: @sln Sorry for that, I've edited the question

Comment: BTW, you must use `^(?!\[.*?\])` or `^(?!\[[^\]\[]*])`

Comment: Wait, are you sure the regex works as expected? `/^[^\[.?\]]/` can't really work, it is erroneous. Also, are you using it in Ruby?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  `^[^\[.?\]]` This works as expected as I want to match a string which doesnot sarts with a bracket and anything written inside it`[xyz]`

Comment: So, it is wrong, and you may easily see that [in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/FIJvq0/2). And this is a [correct regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FIJvq0/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you recommend some good resources for learning Regex?

Comment: I do not know your level of regex knowledge so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: Note that Ruby regex is quite specific (anchors, `m` modifier, recursion levels are not atomic, `[` and `]` inside a character class must be escaped always...), you probably also need to study the [Onigmo docs](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194227/discussion-between-ankit-wadhwana-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `^[^\[.?\]]` pattern is a wrong pattern here because the sequence of patterns is enclosed in a character class. `^[^\[.?\]]` matches any char but `[`, `.`, `?`, `]` at the start of a string. You need to match any line that starts with a sequence of chars, `[`, then any number of chars up to a `]`.

To match a line in Ruby that does not start with `[...]` substring you may use

```
^(?!\[[^\]\[]*]).*
^(?!\[.*?]).*
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/uRG4r3gS5BxQzt) and [the latter regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F!%5C%5B.*%3F%5D).*):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!\[.*?])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right there is `[`, any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possilble and then `]` (note `[^\]\[]*` matches 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and may be preferable if there cannot be any `[` and `]` between the `[...]`)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

Comment: Just in case, see [a Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/sZDrmA), `s.lines.grep(/^(?!\[.*?])/)`

Comment: You gave the perfect solution and it worked.
Thanks a lot for helping me.